# preparing dataset from Excel table for PCA

Tags: python, dataset, pca

I have a very basic question, but can't find the solution. Actually I use python for example for PCA-plots for given datasets (like the iris data) where targets and data are already defined.
Now I must start with an Excel file: 1st column contain the classes (targets) that I want to separate (apple, pear, banana, etc.), columns 2-10 give different chemical-analytical values (potassium, glucose, fructose, etc.)

I import with

raw_data = pd.read_excel('fruittype.xlsx')

What is the easiest way to define the data, targets and target names?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
mydict = [{'a': 1,    'b': 2,    'c': 3,    'd': 4},
          {'a': 100,  'b': 200,  'c': 300,  'd': 400},
          {'a': 1000, 'b': 2000, 'c': 3000, 'd': 4000 }]

df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
y = df.iloc[:, 0]
x = df.iloc[:, 1:]
```